# Mongo database Query

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo database.Please help me in writing the query updation. I already had a collection in mongo and i would like to add a new field in existing object field.the structure is as follows.

```
{
        "_class" : "PersistentContent",
        "originalId" : "2070",
        "videoInfo" : {
                "test1" : ["res"]
        },
}
```

I would like to update the structure to below format.

```
{
        "_class" : "PersistentContent",
        "originalId" : "2070",
        "videoInfo" : {
                "test1" : ["res"],
                "test2" : ["res2"]
        },
}
```

How to update the collection and add  test2 into videoInfo tag.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
db.test.update({"originalId" : "2070"},
{
    $set : { "videoInfo.test2" : ["res2"] }
})
```

Comment: while inserting it manually its is inserting  but when inserting it through jongo mongo java code its not getting inserted

Comment: Your question tagged as mongodb not jongo, and i have no idea about jongo